# Как сделать так, чтобы в PyQt5 при нажатии на кнопку добавлялась ещё одна, при этом текст с нажатой кнопки переносился на новую?

Tags: python, pyqt5, gui, pyqt, qpushbutton

Есть поле, забитое кнопками, при этом только одна из всех видна, и её текст - `+`.

Нужно сделать так, чтобы при нажатии на кнопку `+` появлялась следующая, при этом `+` должен переноситься на новую кнопку, а с нажатой стираться.

Я решил это делать следующим образом: 
создал список всех кнопок, размещённых на `QMainWindow`, затем было, на мой взгляд, логичным сделать отбор с помощью `for / in`, а потом через `if` доделать задачу. 
Но *PyQt* это вообще не устраивает, и он просто завершает работу *Python*.

```
class Message(QMainWindow, Ui_Message):   # сообщения
    
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Message, self).__init__(parent)       
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.setWindowTitle('Сообщения')

        buttons= [pushButton, pushButton_2, pushButton_3, pushButton_4,
                  pushButton_5, pushButton_6, pushButton_7, pushButton_8,
                  pushButton_9, pushButton_10, pushButton_11, pushButton_12,
                  pushButton_13, pushButton_14, pushButton_15, pushButton_16,
                  pushButton_17, pushButton_18, pushButton_19, pushButton_20,
                  pushButton_21, pushButton_22, pushButton_23, pushButton_24]
        for i in buttons:
            if i.text() == "+":
                self.i.setText(_translate("Message", "кнопка была нажата"))
                self.i+1.setText(_translate("Message", "+"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я увидел вашу задачу так:

```
import sys
from random import choices
from PyQt5.Qt import *


class Window(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.btns = 24     # укажите количество кнопок
        self.cols = 4      # укажите количество колонок

        d = { k: v for k, v in [[f'{i}', f'Item{i}'] for i in range(self.btns)]}
        lst = d
        self._lst = [i for i in d]

        self.groupBox = QGroupBox("Кнопка появлялась")
        self.groupBox.setFlat(False)
        self.groupBoxLayout = QGridLayout(self.groupBox)
        self.groupBoxLayout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.groupBoxLayout.setVerticalSpacing(1)
        self.groupBoxLayout.setHorizontalSpacing(1)

        layout = QVBoxLayout(self)        
        layout.addWidget(self.groupBox)
        
        for i, v in enumerate(lst):
            btn = QPushButton(v, objectName=v)       
            btn.setStyleSheet("font-size: 15px;")
            btn.clicked.connect(self.toggle_checkbox)
            self.groupBoxLayout.addWidget(btn, i//self.cols+1, i%self.cols+1)
            
        self.groupBoxLayout.setRowStretch(0, 1)
        self.groupBoxLayout.setRowStretch(i//self.cols+2, 1)
        self.groupBoxLayout.setColumnStretch(0, 1)
        self.groupBoxLayout.setColumnStretch(self.cols+1, 1)
        self.choices_plus()

    def choices_plus(self):   
        if not self._lst:
            return        
        self.btn_plus = choices(self._lst)[0]
        self._lst.pop(self._lst.index(self.btn_plus))
        for i in range(self.groupBoxLayout.count()):
            if self.groupBoxLayout.itemAt(i).widget().text() == self.btn_plus:
               self.groupBoxLayout.itemAt(i).widget().setText('+')
               self.groupBoxLayout.itemAt(i).widget().setStyleSheet('color: #f00')

    def toggle_checkbox(self):
        sender = self.sender()
        if isinstance(sender, QPushButton):
            if sender.text() == '+':
                sender.setText('clicked')
                sender.setStyleSheet('color: #fff')
                self.choices_plus()
        

qss = '''
QPushButton {
    background-color: #f4f9f9;
    height: 60px;
    width: 60px;
    border: none;
}
QPushButton[text='+'] {
    background-color: #0ff;
    color: rgb(0, 0, 255);
    font-size: 25px;
}
QPushButton[text='clicked'] {
    background-color: #f14668;
    font-size: 15px;
}
'''

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setStyleSheet(qss)
    ex = Window()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]